# How do i update observable array in knockout binding handler?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to update the observable array in knockout binding handler. But it is not updating. The following code i tried but nothing worked out.

```
 this.DropdownValues = ko.observableArray([
    { id: 0, type: "Arc",Checked:false },
    { id: 1, type: "Eve",Checked:false },
    { id: 2, type: "Ca",Checked:false },
    { id: 3, type: "test",Checked:false },
 ]);
```

Code I have written inside binding handler.

```
 var value =  valueAccessor();
 var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
 console.log("true");
 valueUnwrapped.map(function(item){
     item[Checked]= true; return item; 
 });

 ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value(valueUnwrapped));
```

But my view still not detecting the values. foreach not refeshing in view.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing quotes around the word `Checked`. It should be `item['Checked']` or `item.Checked` rather than `item[Checked]`.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.updateArray = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
       var value =  valueAccessor();
       var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
       $("#before").text(JSON.stringify(valueUnwrapped));
       console.log("true");
       valueUnwrapped.map(function(item){
           item['Checked']= true; return item; 
       });

       ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value(valueUnwrapped));
    }
}

var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.DropdownValues = ko.observableArray([
    { id: 0, type: "Arc",Checked:false },
    { id: 1, type: "Eve",Checked:false },
    { id: 2, type: "Ca",Checked:false },
    { id: 3, type: "test",Checked:false },
  ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>



Before:<br>
<span id="before"></span>
<div data-bind="updateArray: DropdownValues">
</div>


<br><br>
After:<br>
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(DropdownValues)"></span>
```

Comment: Yes it is working.But observable array not updating when we use change event handler inside binding handler

Comment: Then you could show that in your question too? I'll have a look